# XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///myfilepath/www/aws-sdk?=xxxxxxxxxx

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, amazon-web-services, xmlhttprequest

I am rather new to Phonegap. I am trying to build a simple app with javascript,html and jquery. I am unable to connect to the server even after the appropriate objects are created.

```
 var s3 = new AWS.S3({accessKeyID: accessKey , secretAccessKey: secretKey});

 //listing buckets into the console
 s3.listBuckets(function(error, data) {            
     if (err) { 
         navigator.notification.alert(err);
     }
     else {
         for (var index in data.Buckets) {
             var bucket = data.Buckets[index];
             console.log("Bucket: ", bucket.Name, ' : ', bucket.CreationDate);
         }
    }
```

});

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: The xfhr is the error message I am getting. It is not allowing me to connect to the server at all.I tried launching google from the cmd line with the --allow-file-access-from-files switch but the same problem  persists. The s3 object connects to the AWS server and captures the bucket list (or it is supposed to). Gives me a problem with the aws-sdk first. Please help.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by generating a CORS framework library. Thanks.

Comment: The error repeated. I am now getting a 403 error. Any ideas?